# Getting the Ids of all the children of a list

Tags: javascript

If I have a list with four children like:

```
<ul id="foo">
    <li id="1"></li>
    <li id="2"></li>
    <li id="3"></li>
    <li id="4"></li>
</ul>
```

What would I have to do to get the id's of all the children?

I crafted a function like this:

```
function bar() {
  children = document.getElementById('foo');
  childArr = [children[0], children[1], children[2], children[3]]
  console.log(childArr.map(x=>x.id));
}
```

but it's very ugly and I would imagine there's an easier way to handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*but it's very ugly and I would imagine there's an easier way to handle it.*

The code can be made short, using the latest ES6 syntax, as arrow function is used in the code, I assume that the code will be executed in the environment supporting EcmaScript 6.

Using `Array.from()` on the list of DOM elements will allow to iterate over the elements and `map()` can be used on it.

```js
var ids = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#foo li')).map(e => e.id);
console.log(ids);
```

```html
<ul id="foo">
    <li id="1"></li>
    <li id="2"></li>
    <li id="3"></li>
    <li id="4"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Definitely not that ugly, seems like a fairly elegant solution considering the language at hand.